# Javascript Nested async not returning result

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, nested

For some reason, the second nested async DB function never gets the results returned.   First db call gets some planners from MSSQL needed for a 2nd db call to an OracleDB.  I can see the Oracle query works as i get the results in the db function displayed.

```
 app.get('/api/Scrap/:ParmLocation/:ParmDepartment', (req, res) => {
    var ParmLocation = req.params.ParmLocation;
    var ParmDepartment = req.params.ParmDepartment;
    console.log('/api/Scrap called for ' + ParmLocation + ' Department ' + ParmDepartment + ' @ ' + Date());

    // First get planners for this department
    var query = `SELECT Planners FROM DeptPlanners where Department = '${ParmDepartment}'`
    var PromisePlanners = db.DBQueryBHBrowser(query);
    var Planners = '';
    PromisePlanners.then(function(result) {
        result.recordset.forEach(function(row){
            Planners = Object.values(Object.values(row))[0];
        });
        console.log('/api/Scrap Planners completed @ ' + Date());
        console.log('Planners: ' + Planners);
        var query = `SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(ILTRDJ,-5), 'YYDDD'),'WW') AS Week, SUM(ILTRQT / 1000 * -1) AS TOTQTY, SUM(ILPAID / 100 * -1) AS TOTAMT
        FROM PRODDTA.F4111
        JOIN PRODDTA.F4102 ON ILITM = IBITM AND IBMCU = ILMCU AND IBANPL NOT IN (50030002,50030039)
        JOIN PRODDTA.F4101 ON IMLITM = ILLITM
        JOIN PRODCTL.F5500001 On ILTRDJ = DCGRDT
        LEFT JOIN PRODCTL.F0005 ON ILRCD= LTRIM(F0005.Drky)
        And DRSY='42' AND DRRT='RC'
        WHERE ILMCU = '       50010' AND ILDCT IN('ID', 'IS')
        AND ILTRDJ BETWEEN  123001 AND 123365
        AND IBANPL IN (${Planners})
        AND ILRCD NOT IN('517','509') AND ILUSER <> 'HIPPK'
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(ILTRDJ,-5), 'YYDDD'),'WW')
        ORDER BY Week`

        var PromiseScrap = db.DBQueryJDE(query);
        PromiseScrap.then(function(result) {
            //if (debugMode == true) {
                console.log(`/api/Scrap ${ParmLocation} ${ParmDepartment}  completed @ ${Date()}`);
                console.log(`JDE Data:` + result );      // This is always 'Undefined'
            //}
            res.send(result);
        }).catch(function () {
            console.log("Promise Rejected for api/Scrap");
        });
    }).catch(function () {
        console.log("Promise Rejected for /api/Scrap get Planners");
    });
})
```

The second call DBQueryJDE has

```
    async function DBQueryJDE(sqlquery)  {
  try {
    //if (debugMode) {
      console.log('Oracle SQL:\n' + sqlquery);
    //}
    var oracledb = require('oracledb');
    var connectionProperties = {
      user: process.env.DBAAS_USER_NAME || "SomeUserID",
      password: process.env.DBAAS_USER_PASSWORD || "SomePassword",
      connectString: "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = db92IF.bherp.local)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME= DB92IF.bherp.local)))"};
    oracledb.getConnection(connectionProperties, function (err, connection) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        response.status(500).send("Error connecting to DB");
        return;
      }
      connection.execute(sqlquery,
        function (err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            response.status(500).send("Error getting data from JDE DB");
            doRelease(connection);
            return;
          }
          console.log("RESULTSET:" + JSON.stringify(result));
          doRelease(connection);
          //console.log('returned from close');
          return result;
        }
      );
    });
    //return result;
  } catch (error) {
      console.log('DBErrorJDE: ' + err.message + '\n Query:' + sqlquery);
      doRelease(connection);
      return;
  }
};
```

The results in console are

node app
Dashboard server listening on port 3000

/api/Scrap called for BHNW Department Manifolds @ Wed May 03 2023 09:19:54 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

/api/Scrap Planners completed @ Wed May 03 2023 09:19:54 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

Planners: 50030015,50030029

Oracle SQL: SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(ILTRDJ,-5), 'YYDDD'),'WW') AS Week, SUM(ILTRQT / 1000 * -1) AS TOTQTY, SUM(ILPAID / 100 * -1) AS TOTAMT
FROM PRODDTA.F4111
JOIN PRODDTA.F4102 ON ILITM = IBITM AND IBMCU = ILMCU AND IBANPL NOT IN (50030002,50030039)
JOIN PRODDTA.F4101 ON IMLITM = ILLITM
JOIN PRODCTL.F5500001 On ILTRDJ = DCGRDT
LEFT JOIN PRODCTL.F0005 ON ILRCD= LTRIM(F0005.Drky)
And DRSY='42' AND DRRT='RC'
WHERE ILMCU = '       50010' AND ILDCT IN('ID', 'IS')
AND ILTRDJ BETWEEN  123001 AND 123365
AND IBANPL IN (50030015,50030029)
AND ILRCD NOT IN('517','509') AND ILUSER <> 'HIPPK'
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(SUBSTR(ILTRDJ,-5), 'YYDDD'),'WW')
ORDER BY Week

/api/Scrap BHNW Manifolds  completed @ Wed May 03 2023 09:19:54 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)

JDE Data:undefined

RESULTSET:{"metaData":[{"name":"WEEK"},{"name":"TOTQTY"},{"name":"TOTAMT"}],"rows":[["01",24,1573.83],["02",35,2096.06],["03",26,903.28],["04",16,729.95],["05",25,873.44],["06",61,2015.3500000000001],["07",28,2293.91],["08",23,1223.8500000000001],["09",24,800.9],["10",41,1366.04],["11",17,1712.95],["12",30,1588.1200000000001],["13",45,1189.51],["14",33,1104.3],["15",71,2378.3],["16",38,1430.72],["17",35,2559.43],["18",22,725.89]]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are using a mix of `callback` AND `async/promise` in your nested function.

You are invoking your nested function `DBQueryJDE` as if it returns a Promise:

```
const result = await DBQueryJDE(query)
```

But the way the function is implemented - it will always return `undefined` because it is using callbacks.

The reason is that you are returning the result from the callback - which is not getting returned to the caller.

i.e. This is what you are doing

```
function DBQueryJDE(queryString) {
     // when you get a connection - you then execute a callback function which is passed the connection
     oracledb.getConnection(args, (connection) => {
          // when connection.execute is executed - the following callback is executed with the results
          connection.execute(queryString, (results) => {
              // now you have the results - you need to either execute another callback or do nothing as this cannot be returned via the existing pattern
              return results; // this does not get returned to the caller.
          }
     })

}
```

As of version 5.5 of `oracledb` according to their examples - they support promises so you can modify as follows and this return will be returned to the caller.

For a better understanding I suggest you read on the differences between callbacks and async/promises.

```
const connection = await oracledb.getConnection(connectionProperties); 
return connection.execute(sqlquery);
```

(You can use the oracledb async or you could also roll your own and wrap the DBQueryJDE functions internal callbacks in a Promise as follows)

```
async function DBQueryJDE(sqlquery)  {
      try {
        ...
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
            oracledb.getConnection(connectionProperties, function (err, connection) {
            if (err) return reject(err);
          
            connection.execute(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
               if (err) return reject(err)
                 return resolve(result);
            });
        });
      } catch (error) {
        ...
      }
    };
```

Also - if you are getting multiple rows back from your first query, you are going to overwrite your `Planners` variable and lose values. Looks like you should be appending to the variable - not re-assigning it.

```
var Planners = '';
...
result.recordset.forEach(function(row){
    Planners = Object.values(Object.values(row))[0];
});
```

Comment: Thank you Jeeves!  I am back to that project and will give it a go...

Comment: Worked great. When connection is closed?
...
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      oracledb.getConnection(connectionProperties, function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Oracle Connect Error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
          return reject(err);
        } else {

        }
        connection.execute(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
              console.log('Oracle Execute error: ' + JSON.stringify(err));
              return reject(err);
            }
            return resolve(result);
        })
      })...

Comment: Not sure if that is another question or not @SteveGrody ? If it is, perhaps you should open another question for that one?